# How to disable WordWrap in Java JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, word-wrap

My program has a problem.. It is WordWrap is abled...

Exactly, I want to use linwrap but i don't want wordwrap...

I searched this

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
JPanel noWrapPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
noWrapPanel.add( textPane );
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( noWrapPanel );
```

When i use this code, Both linewrap and wordwrap are disabled....

I want to make use linewrap....

sorry my terrible English skill...
I believe you can get what i mean
please help me...

Comment: `I believe you can get what i mean please help me...` - not really. Using JDK7 on Window7 I don't get "word wrap". That is a complete word is moved to a new line when wrapping occurs, which I believe is the correct behaviour. Maybe I don't understand what you mean by word wrap. If you want the text to wrap in the middle of the word then you can use a JTextArea. Otherwise you can post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is :

[Link for it](http://java-sl.com/wrap.html)

```
// Override getScrollableTracksViewportWidth
// to preserve the full width of the text
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
    Component parent = getParent();
    ComponentUI ui = getUI();

    return parent != null ? (ui.getPreferredSize(this).width <= parent
        .getSize().width) : true;
}
```

[Other link](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
JTextPane textPane;

public void someMethod() {  
    textPane = new JTextPane(new DefaultStyledDocument());
    textPane.setEditorKit(new ExtendedStyledEditorKit());
}


/** To enable no wrap to JTextPane **/
static class ExtendedStyledEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final ViewFactory styledEditorKitFactory = (new StyledEditorKit()).getViewFactory();

    private static final ViewFactory defaultFactory = new ExtendedStyledViewFactory();

    public Object clone() {
        return new ExtendedStyledEditorKit();
    }

    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        return defaultFactory;
    }

    /* The extended view factory */
    static class ExtendedStyledViewFactory implements ViewFactory {
        public View create(Element elem) {
            String elementName = elem.getName();
            if (elementName != null) {
                if (elementName.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)) {
                    return new ExtendedParagraphView(elem);
                }
            }

            // Delegate others to StyledEditorKit
            return styledEditorKitFactory.create(elem);
        }
    }

}

static class ExtendedParagraphView extends ParagraphView {
    public ExtendedParagraphView(Element elem) {
        super(elem);
    }

    @Override
    public float getMinimumSpan(int axis) {
        return super.getPreferredSpan(axis);
    }
}
```